# Find a regex match and replace start

Tags: regex

I have huge amount of special strings containing coordinates and other information.

What I need to do is find a matching string that starts with a `G1` and ends with `F4500`, afterwards in that matching string I have replace the `G1` with a `G0`.

Example:

Initial: `G1 X95.090 Y104.910 F4500`

Modified: `G0 X95.090 Y104.910 F4500`

I was breaking my head over this for quite some time now and can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Are you using a specific language?

Comment: What language are you doing this in? How is this data fed into your application? Do all strings start with a sequence like `G1` or `G0`? If so, you could do this easily without regex.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern matches the string to replace:

`\bG1(?=.*?F4500\b)`

```
\b    // a word boundary
G1    // literal
(?=   // look ahead and assert that group matches
.*?   // anything
F4500 // literal
\b    // a word boundary
)     // end of group
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LxKTXI/2)

In Java you could do:

```
"target string here".replaceAll("the regex pattern", "G0");
```

Answer (score 0):

with **sed**:

```
$ echo 'G1 X95.090 Y104.910 F4500' | sed -e 's/G1\(.*F4500\)/G0\1/'
```

So if you're have your strings in a file:

```
$ sed -i -e 's/G1\(.*F4500\)/G0\1/' input.txt
```